# I somehow tore-off my notifications on my iPad…

Tags: bug, notifications, ipad

I don’t know what I did, but whenever I open the Stack Exchange notifications menu and tap on items on my iPad, it does this and I can’t seem to dismiss it.

I honestly don’t know if this is something new iPad OS - or a bug in some JavaScript on SO.

[image]

Comment: Nah, that's *surely* a feature.  You don't get this kind of thing by accident.  Sometimes I wish I could rip up some of those too, y'know. :D

Comment: Do you by chance have a "Turn Notifications Into Torn Off Graphics" plugin installed?  Or, more seriously, any other Safari plugins that could be modifying the page?

Comment: @AnonCoward Nope, my iOS and Safari is all stock - not even jailbroken (I know, I'm an embarrassment).

Comment: Clearly, this was not an atomic operation. The inbox just happens to be tearable. It's what happens when there are more notifications in the inbox than what can fit in the registers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a feature of iOS 15+ and iPadOS, not SO. If you hold down on a link and drag you "grab" that link; while doing so you can tap on other links to drag them too. You can use another finger to navigate to the tab switcher in your mobile browser and release them to open up each link in a new tab, like I'm doing here in Chrome:

[image: chrome tab switcher]

Notice the color difference in the screenshots: Green (with plus sign) means something will happen if you drop it there and blue means lifting your fingers will cancel the grab.

Also, this same thing is possible with text and images too, which could be handy if already had something on your clipboard and wanted to copy something else too. You can also grab multiple copies of the same selected text, but I don't know how that would useful — I think you're supposed to mix and match with grabbing links and images.

---

If lifting all your fingers from the screen doesn't drop the links/images/text you're grabbing, there may be something wrong with your iPad, possibly the touch screen is going bad. Do you have issues with other gestures? I have no problems on my iPhone: Releasing my fingers drops what I'm grabbing.

Comment: _"If lifting all your fingers from the screen doesn't drop the links/images/text you're grabbing, there may be something wrong with your iPad, possibly the touch screen is going bad."_ - There are no problems with the touchscreen AFAICT, but occasional (software-based, app-level) glitches with touch detection are not unheard-of with iOS - so let's chalk it up to gremlins?